# Mail.app not showing the "synchronize" option for an IMAP account

Tags: mail.app, gmail, macos, imap

I have 6 different IMAP accounts configured on Mail (all of them for gmail / google apps accounts).

All of them, **except one**, have a "Synchronize" option in the menu that appears when right-clicking any of the inboxes or other IMAP folders in the left pane.

This one account which doesn't have this option also has occasional major lags in syncing with the server.

*ALL of the account settings are identical* (including enabling of IDLE).

Any ideas what could be causing this and how to resolve?

Comment: does it show in the list under mailbox tab -synchronize

Comment: @Buscar웃 which "tab" are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Look for it in the Mail--Mailbox--Synchronization

if not there..

Sounds like when setting up that account something went wrong

reset that account

remove it and add it new